# Achieve AnticipateOvershootInterpolator animation in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uislider

I have a group of a few UISlider controls that I need to animate, from a value to another value.

The requirement for the animation is that it needs to match (as close as possible) the effect of [AnticipateOvershootInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnticipateOvershootInterpolator.html) from the Android platform.
The documentation for `AnticipateOvershootInterpolator` mentions:

> An interpolator where the change starts backward then flings forward
>   and overshoots the target value and finally goes back to the final
>   value.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bECXXQaseYc) with the animation, taken from [this blog](https://dotblogs.com.tw/kent2480/archive/2015/07/12/151837.aspx).

This is the structure that I have in place. For the sake of this question, the focus will be on 1 UISlider.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:1.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.slider setValue:100 animated:YES];
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         //some other stuff
                     }
}];
```

I was hoping to find an appropriate value for the `options` parameter (`UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` in my code, sadly doesn't match the effect wanted) that would match the `AnticipateOvershootInterpolator` effect.
I am also aware that maybe this effect is not possible to be achieved with the `animateWithDuration` method, therefore any suggestions are welcome.

**How can I achieve the `AnticipateOvershootInterpolator` effect on the iOS platform?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve it with UIView animations then your best bet should be **Keyframe animation**

```
 UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, options: [], animations: { 
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        // start animation update your values here
    })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.24, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: { 
        // update the postion values here
    })

    // continue adding at least 2 more keyframes with relative start and change your values as you like them
}, completion: nil)
```

To do an animation like that or even do it better than that. You have to look into UIKit Dynamics

```
// self.view can be any view 
let animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
```

It has a lot of useful options
You have to look into UIKit Dynamic behaviours

- UIGravityBehavior
- UIFieldBehavior
- UISnapBehavior

in UIFieldBehaviour you have many useful behaviour and the one you should look specifically will be ElectricField also use thing the UISnapBehavior

Answer (score 0):

You can create the anticipating effect by first making a regular animations which decreases the value (that needs to be animated), and in that completion bock add `animate​With​Duration:​delay:​using​Spring​With​Damping:​initial​Spring​Velocity:​options:​animations:​completion` to animate the sliders value with a overshoot effect :)

Smth like this

```
[self.slider setValue:30 animated:NO];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:1.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.slider setValue:25 animated:YES];
               } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   if (finished) {
                       [UIView animateWithDuration:duration 
                                             delay:0 
                            usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
                             initialSpringVelocity:0.0f 
                                           options:0 
                                        animations:^{
                                            [self.slider setValue:80 animated:NO];
                                      } completion:nil];
                 }
}];
```

Hope it works :)